# How to make a multiple language Dialogflow webhook/fulfillment?

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, i18next, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have built a Dialogflow app in english. I used a NodeJs webhook to provide the answers.

Now, I want to add a new language (Spanish). Is there a way to add it without duplicating the webhook?

Is there a prebuilt Library ,like I18N, where I provide the translation and depending on the `"languageCode": "en"`, I send the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution is for you to use a localization library of your choice, send it a string identifier, and send the response that it generates. There are [several libraries](https://developers.google.com/actions/localization/fulfillment) that Google suggests, however you should be able to use whichever one works best for you. There are some issues using [i18n-node](https://github.com/mashpie/i18n-node) if you are using asynchronous code - the problems and solutions are also [discussed by the team](https://medium.com/google-developers/5-tips-when-localizing-your-action-adding-different-languages-b4213cc9573f).

There is also the [multivocal library](https://multivocal.info/), which takes a different approach to generating responses, but has localization built-in.